# How can I reverse a list in foreach?

Tags: c#, list

I have a problem, I cant reverse the following `List`:

```
foreach (List<Foo> row in Items) 
{
    foreach (Foo item in row.Reverse())
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

I always get the error:

> Type void is not enumerable

Whats the problem and how to solve it?

Comment: According to this post, it seems they have changed the signature of the Reverse method in a recent version of .NET: public static IEnumerable<TSource> Reverse<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source);

Answer (score 38, accepted):

[`List<T>.Reverse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5c6526tb.aspx) doesn't *return* anything - it reverses the list in place.

If you want to use the [LINQ version of `Reverse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358497.aspx) which returns a reversed sequence but *without* mutating the existing list, you could use:

```
foreach (IEnumerable<Foo> row in Items) 
{
    foreach (Foo item in row.Reverse())
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Or perhaps more clearly:

```
foreach (List<Foo> row in Items) 
{
    // We want to use the LINQ to Objects non-invasive
    // Reverse method, not List<T>.Reverse
    foreach (Foo item in Enumerable.Reverse(row))
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 20):

[`List<T>.Reverse()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0axc2h2.aspx) does an *in-place* reverse. That means it changes your original list.

So, you would use it like this:

```
foreach (List<Foo> row in Items) 
{
    row.Reverse();
    foreach (Foo item in row)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

If you don't want to change your original list, you will have to call [`Enumerable.Reverse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358497.aspx) explicitly:

```
foreach (List<Foo> row in Items) 
{
    foreach (Foo item in Enumerable.Reverse(row))
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

The reason for not being able to use `Enumerable.Reverse` in the extension method syntax is: Extension methods don't hide / override instance methods and `List<T>` happens to already have a `Reverse` method.

Comment: +1 for emphasizing the original list is *changed* and therefore *is and remains reversed* at different parts of the program.

Answer (score 5):

[`List<T>.Reverse()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0axc2h2.aspx) is an *in-place* reverse, it doesn't return a *new list*. It changes your **orininal** list.

> Reverses the order of the elements in the entire `List<T>`.

You need to use `row.Reverse();` in your first foreach statement. Like;

```
foreach (List<Foo> row in Items) 
{
    row.Reverse();
    foreach (Foo item in row)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Here is a **[DEMO](http://ideone.com/1g2hTO)**.

If you don't want to change your *orininal list*, you can use **[Enumerable.Reverse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358497.aspx)** method instead of.

> Inverts the order of the elements in a sequence.

```
foreach (Foo item in Enumerable.Reverse(row))
{
    //
}
```

Here is the same **[DEMO](http://ideone.com/9UH9re)** with using `Enumerable.Reverse<T>` method.

Answer (score 4):

```
foreach (List<Foo> row in Items) 
{
    row.Reverse()
    foreach (Foo item in row)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

`Reverse` change order within the list - it does not return new list with reversed order of items.

Answer (score 3):

`List<T>.Reverse` do not return anything all it!

```
foreach (IEnumerable<Foo> row in Items) 
{
    row.Reverse();
    foreach(Foo item in row)
    {

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

List.Reverse() is a method with a void signature.

You can probably change your loop as below.

```
foreach (List<Foo> row in Items) 
{
    row.Reverse();
    foreach (Foo item in row)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```